# ViewController loading twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I'm using a combination of objective C and swift 3.

In my mainView (Objective C) I have the following

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    CourseViewController *courseView = (CourseViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"courseView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:courseView animated:YES];
```

In my storyboard, my mainView will Show a Navigation Controller that's rootView to the swift 3 view.

In the swift 3 view controller I have the following and the loadView and viewDidLoad gets called twice

```
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()

    //If you want to implement the delegate
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self

    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let temp: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    screenSize = temp
    let url = URL(string: kcourseURL)
    let req = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.load(req)
    //webView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:navBarHeight, width:Int(screenSize.width), height:Int(screenSize.height))

    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

    self.setBarButton()


}
```

Any suggestion on why it's being called twice?

Also, I'm trying to dismiss this view to go back to the mainView but it doesn't get called if I use a navigation Controller on the swift 3 view. I've tried the following. Do I need to use a segue unwind to go back to the mainView?

```
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Why do you instantiate the view controller explicitly when using Storyboard anyway?

Comment: Do you have a segue set up in `Storyboard` between the two viewControllers?

Comment: I have segue setup in storyboard between the 2 view. The course view has a nav controller as a root view. I instantiate the view explicitly because I do that in objective c, don't know how that changes when I do a objective c to Swift implementation. If I don't instantiate it, the view doesn't get called just with the storyboard setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using in your application navigation controller then here one thing I need to clear here if you are using **Segue** for navigation then no need to call the same view again here with the help of **code** choose only one process here. Navigation will depend on you which type you want like push, show, present modally and present as popover.

after that need to use only one line for back to view or back to root view: -

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**OR**

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**OR**
for back Rootview

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

For navigation, one StoryBoard to another: -

**Objective-C**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *second = (SecondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

**Swift 3**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Customer", bundle: nil)
let secondVC =   storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

**And Try with Segue**

First need to take storyBoard reference then add storyBoardname then add inside Referenced Id as your ViewController's StoryBoard ID.

[image: add Storyboard reference]

and also confirm your destination controller's **Storyboard ID**

[image: View Controller's StoryBoard ID]

and Finally PerformSegue with data segue identifier: -

```
 let segueIdentifier = "fourthView"

 //MARK: - Navigation
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier {
          let controller = segue.destination as! FourthVC
          //Passing Values here
          controller.promoViewModel =  promotionModel[0]
        }
    }
```

Output will be like below image no need to do any extra things: -

[image: OutPut View]

Comment: I'm using a segue and in the Perform segue, I call the following UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];     CourseViewController *courseView = (CourseViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"courseView"];     [self.navigationController pushViewController:courseView animated:YES];

Comment: I've tried all 3 of those and it does not dismiss and go back to the root view. These work if I don't use a navigation view as the root view but then I lose the nav bar of all my buttons

Comment: you performing segue in same storyboard or another storyboard? If you performing segue from one storyboard to another story here i am updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the only thing I need was [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"training" sender:self]; and then a segue in the storyboard called training.

I added another call in the prepareForSegue which triggered the view again. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Chech if where you called the `loadView()` method, because your code is not all post, if is:

You should not call `loadView()` directly, accoring to apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview)

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.
>
> If the view controller has an associated nib file, this method loads the view from the nib file. A view controller has an associated nib file if the nibName property returns a non-nil value, which occurs if the view controller was instantiated from a storyboard, if you explicitly assigned it a nib file using the init(nibName:bundle:) method, or if iOS finds a nib file in the app bundle with a name based on the view controller's class name. If the view controller does not have an associated nib file, this method creates a plain UIView object instead.

This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if they aren't using a nib. Should never be called directly.

No matter you load view for Xib or create view by yourself, `viewDidLoad` will always be invoked after the view be loaded.

Take your code below:

```
webView = WKWebView()

//If you want to implement the delegate
webView?.navigationDelegate = self

view = webView
```

from `loadView()` to `viewDidLoad()`, and delete the `loadView()` method.

---

**Edit - 1**

I have write a demo for testing your mixed project, and I find its not because of `loadView()`, I tried use `perform segue` and use `navigationController push`, did not work, so my answer is not fit you, I am find why there is the issue in the mixed demo, strange.

Comment: I can't see where `loadView()` is called in the question.

Comment: I'm not calling loadView, it's called automatically. But in my implementation, loadView and viewdidload is being triggered twice so my view loads twice.